# Не удается отправить POST-запрос laravel

Tags: laravel, post, chat

Делаю чат на laravel 5.6, но не работает отправка сообщений. Код контроллера отправки сообщений:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\AjaxChat;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SendChatController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // отправка сообщения
        $sender = $request->sender();
        $text = $request->message();
        $message = "\n<li id='down' class='left clearfix'>$sender написал: $text</li>"; // шаблон нашего сообщения
        $filename = asset('storage/txts/messages.txt');
        $file = fopen($filename, 'a'); // открываем файл для редакции
        fwrite($file, $message); // записываем отправленное сообщение в чат
        fclose($file); // закрываем фай
    }
}
```

код представления chat.blade.php:

```
<head>
    <meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/chat.css')}}"><script>

    //ajax setup
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
    });

    //send func
    function send() {
        var name = $('.name>input').val();
        var message = $('.message>input').val(); // сообщение
        $.post("/Chat/Send", {'sender': name, 'message': message});
    }

    //show messages
    function show() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{route("chatShow")}}',
            timeout: 10000, // время ожидания
            success: function (data) {
                $('#messages').html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#messages').html("Не удалось загрузить");
            }
        });
    }

    var interval = 5000; // ожидание

    show();

    //auto messages update
    setInterval('show()', interval);

</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary" style="max-height: 300px;">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
                    Chat
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body scroll" style=" max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
                    <ul id="messages" style="list-style-type: none;">
                    </ul>
                    <div class="down"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <form method="POST">
                        <div class="name">
                            <input id="btn-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm"
                                   placeholder="Type your name here..."/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="message">
                                <input id="message" type="text" class="form-control input-sm"
                                       placeholder="Type your message here..."/>
                            </div>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button onclick="send()" type="submit" id="send_form" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
                                        id="btn-chat">
                                    Send
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-primary" id="send_message_result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

роут:

```
//Send

Route::post('/Chat/Send','AjaxChat\SendChatController@index')->name('chatSend');
```

Используется стандартный ajax чат, без laravel работает, с ним нет, laravel v5.6.

Comment: Ошибку Выдает или что? Тяжело понять почему у Вас не работает. И как должно работать.

Comment: нет просто в консоле браузера пишет 'Error 500 /Chat/Send (iternal server error)' и сразу видает экран ошибки laravel 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException'

Comment: я нашел что надо сначала просто в ajax js поставить тип запроса сначала post потом перезагрузить страницу , потом get перезагрузить , и да вы угадали снова post и перезагрузить и чудо оно заработало (я три дня с єтим провозился ,но надеюсь что это кому-то поможет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я нашел что надо сначала просто в ajax js поставить тип запроса сначала post потом перезагрузить страницу , потом get перезагрузить , и да вы угадали снова post и перезагрузить и чудо оно заработало (я три дня с етим провозился ,но надеюсь что это кому-то поможет) 
p.s (для новичков) не надо писать свои предложения так как автор сам нашел решение

Answer (score 0):

попробуй в VerifyCsrfToken отключить верификацию
    protected $except = [
    '/Chat/Send',
    ];